# Gray background for html5 video in FireFox

Tags: css, html, firefox, html5-video

I am adding a html5 video to a web page

```
 <video  width="610" height="571" controls="controls" poster="image.jpg">
```

The background of this video is gray in FireFox , however I added the poster attribute to the video tag to insert an image but  the gray background still wrapping the poster image and showing a gray frame background  around it

I tried to the `background-color:transparent !important`; rule to the video tag but nothing changed 
How can I change the background color for the html5 video tag in FireFox ?

Answer (score -1):

This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30591117/550454 by [intika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4877948/intika)

> ## ***Solution :***
>
> *CSS*
>
> ```
> .brightness{
>     filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter
> ```
>
> id=\'brightness\'>#brightness");
>   /* Firefox 3.5+ */
>           -webkit-filter:brightness(108.5%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
>       }
>
> *HTML*
>
> ```
> <div class="brightness">
> <video src="http://www.botlibre.com/media/a786628.mp4">
> </video>
> </div>
> ```
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/27L5nvg4/1/
>
> ---
>
> ## ***Solution Demonstration***
>
> ```css
> > 
> >     .brightness{
> >         filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter
> > id=\'brightness\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1.2 0 0 0 0
> > 0 1.2 0 0 0 0 0 1.2 0 0 0 0 0 1.2 0\'/></filter></svg>#brightness");
> > /* Firefox 3.5+ */
> >         -webkit-filter:brightness(108.5%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
> >     }
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> ```html
> > 
> >     <div class="brightness">
> >     <video src="http://www.botlibre.com/media/a786628.mp4">
> >     </video>
> >     </div>
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ## ***Problem Demonstration***
>
> ```css
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> ```html
> > 
> >     <div class="brightness">
> >     <video src="http://www.botlibre.com/media/a786628.mp4">
> >     </video>
> >     </div>
> > 
> >
> ```
>
> ---

Comment: If the questions are so identical that the same answer works for both, consider flagging the question as a duplicate instead.

Comment: And you should at least credit the actual author of the code (by username) in addition to the link.  See [How to reference material written by others](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)