# Firefox, Chrome, Safari have grey background for MP4 HTML5 video

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, ffmpeg, html5-video

Any video (that I can make) with a white background becomes grey in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari (it is white in IE). Well, on my Windows machine it is grey, on my Android phone/tablet and Mac it is white...

I am using ffmpeg to encode the video. If I encode it as webm, the background is white.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbg8f6ck/

I found a hack that fixes it for Chrome:

```
<video style="-webkit-filter:brightness(108.5%);"
```

But it does not work for Firefox or Safari.

Another hack for Firefox:

```
filter:brightness(1.085)
```

But for some reason setting it through JavaScript does not work.

A few versions ago the background was white for Chrome, then became grey again...

The question is: Why is white grey?

Is it an issue with the video or with Chrome, Firefox, Safari in general? (How can they not support white?)

Is it possible to get a white background?

Any hacks, workarounds?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145535/color-correcting-mp4-webm-videos

Comment: This may also be of interest: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/36322/why-isnt-the-black-in-a-video-made-with-after-effects-a-true-black-when-its-vi

Comment: Please provide a sample MP4 file that exhibits this behavior. The botlibre link is currently invalid.

Answer (score 14):

After a long search and tests here is a working solution

## ***Solution :***

*CSS*

```
.brightness{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'brightness\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1.2 0 0 0 0 0 1.2 0 0 0 0 0 1.2 0 0 0 0 0 1.2 0\'/></filter></svg>#brightness"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    -webkit-filter:brightness(108.5%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="brightness">
<video src="http://www.botlibre.com/media/a786628.mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/27L5nvg4/1/

---

## ***Solution Demonstration***

```css
.brightness{
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'brightness\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1.2 0 0 0 0 0 1.2 0 0 0 0 0 1.2 0 0 0 0 0 1.2 0\'/></filter></svg>#brightness"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    -webkit-filter:brightness(108.5%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}
```

```html
<div class="brightness">
<video src="http://www.botlibre.com/media/a786628.mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

---

## ***Problem Demonstration***

```html
<div class="brightness">
<video src="http://www.botlibre.com/media/a786628.mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

---

***Alternative Workarounds :***

Try using an other html video player
http://html5video.org/wiki/HTML5_Video_Player_Comparison

You can change you page background to gray for firefox etc. to match your video

Also if it's just the women talking you can use gif animation with audio

***Capture Firefox :***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWWqm.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  However for the solution I just see a white page, no video at all.  If I remove the filter then the video shows.  Also, do you see white or grey on your machine?  My main concern is what other people see, not what I see.

Comment: Hi :) i am on firefox v24.8 windows 8 and i see grayed video on snipped problems and white back on solution i have just posted a capture

Comment: Odd, I still see the filter one as just blank white

Comment: It works on all except firefox. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: I am really glad that this solved my issue for chrome in mac OS but it does rectify on safari :(

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Any idea *why* the background is grey?

Comment: Still a problem (and still a solid solution) in 2020! +1

Answer (score 5):

In many cases it is a problem of **nVidia drivers**.
NVIDIA video card users try the following:

1. open the NVIDIA Control Panel
2. under "Video" select “Adjust video color settings”
3. under "How do you make color adjustments" select “With the NVIDIA settings”
4. under "Advanced" make sure "Dynamic Range" is “**Full (0-255)**” not “Limited (16-235)” (“Dynamic contrast enhancement” should be unchecked)

In my case it worked, anyway I don't understand why Dynamic range for video is limited by default...

See here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138024

Answer (score 0):

As the brightness-workaround made everything brighter than white (yeah right) in iOS, i had to find another workaround.

The (better) workaround is to set a border-radius for **0.000001%** or bigger. Then it does not show white as gray anymore.

```
<video autoplay loop playsinline muted style="border-radius:0.000001%;">
    <source src="whatever.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Hope it helps, cheers

Answer (score -2):

Chrome will default to a different video encoding using an open source HTML5 video codec.
The other browsers such as FireFox, Safari and IE will default to using Flash.

Comment: html video are not played with flash by default